# jQuery FlipClock TwentyFourHourClock show with full date

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I'm working with jQuery FlipClock. Plugin is [here](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/tree/master/examples)

My question, is it possible to adding the full date together with time?
As my below code, it's only show me the time.

I just wondering if it's possible to show the full date and time.

Example,

```
var date = new Date();
            
clock = $('.clock2').FlipClock(date, {
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
    showSeconds: true
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="clock2"></div>
```

So the output will be, example: 25-JAN-2021 08:30:00

*It's for clock, not for counter.

Comment: Make a runnable stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `FlipClock.Face` which shows date built in to the plugin. If you want to display the date, you'll need to write your own.

A good place to start is [the `Face` you're currently using](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/blob/master/src/flipclock/js/faces/twentyfourhourclock.js).

Comment: Hi, which part I need to do the modification?

Comment: Create a new `Face`